# git diff last commit plus all uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a repo on a brach, and I have some uncommitted changes.

```
$ git status
<my local changes>
```

I also have a previous "work in progress" commit with a lot of diffs in, made by a colleague.

```
$ git log
commit 6b388883f3e3cf2a864aeb335ce36e10f0e7a60d
Date:   Thu Jan 15 12:39:26 2015 +0000

    Work in progress

commit 91c868cda56e309b9a417f21c929a1beb1cc74d4
Date:   Thu Jan 14 12:39:26 2015 +0000

    <Last "real" commit to master>
```

I'm now planning to create a new branch based off master (aka `91c868cda56e309b9a417f21c929a1beb1cc74d4`), and make a brand new set of neat structured commits, to make a clean PR.

To do that, it would be very helpful to output a single diff, with all the changes made (both committed and uncommitted) since the last "real" commit, `91c868cda56e309b9a417f21c929a1beb1cc74d4`.

This is a throwaway branch, so it doesn't matter what I do on this branch.

What's the best way to do this?

One idea I had is that I could commit all my local changes, and then diff between that commit and `91c868cda56e309b9a417f21c929a1beb1cc74d4`: is it possible to see a single diff of all the changes between those two commits?

Comment: Are you sure you just want to see the changes? You don't want to just produce a new commit that *contains* those changes? I would suggest that you commit your change son your current WIP branch, and then check out your new branch from `master` and `git merge --squash <wip branch>`, which would merge all the changes into the index, ready to be committed.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to split the changes out into more granular commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `git diff` you have to select two sets-of-files to compare.  You can do this by specifying two revisions explicitly, e.g., `git diff HEAD~3 HEAD^`, which diffs those two commits.  Or, you can diff some commit with your work-tree, or with your index/staging-area; or compare your index/staging-area to your work-tree.

To diff one commit against your current work-tree, name one commit: `git diff HEAD`, `git diff HEAD^`, `git diff HEAD~2`, and so on.  If you do not name a particular commit, however, `git diff` compares your index/staging area against your work-tree, rather than using the `HEAD` commit.

To diff one commit against your index/staging area, name one commit and also use `--cached`: `git diff --cached HEAD~2`, and so on.  Name *no* commits and git defaults to using `HEAD` here.

If you name *two* commits, `git diff` compares those two commits.  You can write both of them as separate commits, `git diff HEAD~2 HEAD` for instance, or you can use the `..` format: `git diff HEAD~2..HEAD`.  Here `--cached` makes no sense, since it means "use index instead of work-directory" and the diff is not using the work-dir.

In your particular case here, comparing `HEAD^`, which names commit `91c868cda56e309b9a417f21c929a1beb1cc74d4`, to your work-tree is what you want now.  If you *do* make a new commit now, though, comparing `HEAD^^` (or explicit commit `91c868cda56e309b9a417f21c929a1beb1cc74d4`) to your new commit will be what you want.  Your new commit will be the new `HEAD` so you can diff `HEAD^^` vs `HEAD` at that point.

See [the `gitrevisions` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for many ways to spell particular revisions.

---

Note that additional arguments that are not diff flags (diff flags being things like `-w` to ignore white space) are taken as path-specifiers, to limit the set of files diffed.  For instance, if you're just curious what happened to `path/to/file.txt` between two revisions:

```
git diff rev1 rev2 path/to/file.txt
```

If a file name "looks like" a diff flag (what if you want to see what happened to the file named `--cached` for instance?) you can use `--` to separate "arguments meant to control the diff itself" from "path names meant to limit which paths are diffed".